# Im am trying to create custom authorize attribute on my web api mvc 4 application in visual basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes

I am trying to implement my custom authorize attribute that inherits system.web.http.authorizeAttribute
in my project i have a web api mvc 4 template and a mvc4 internet application template
with windows authentication as a client. i have some methods in the web api controller which i am trying to not make accessible for the authenticated user that sends the request
in exchange if he hits the button that has the custom attribute, a 401 should be return. and also if he is not authenticated the client shouldn't see things that are not authorized to see

please help with some code example!!!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and tell us where you are stuck.  What is your solution doing and what are you trying to get it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a custom AuthorizeAttribute deriving from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute you should override the IsAuthorized() method. It is pretty simple as shown below.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Do some condition check here

        // Return the result of the condition check
        return isAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Now add `[MyAuthorizeAttribute]` attribute to the methods you want to secure. This will cause a 401 to be returned for all unauthenticated requests to those methods.

A better way is to add `[MyAuthorizeAttribute]` to the Controller and `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to the methods which does not need authentication.

Comment: @LeandroTupone There are different ways of working with custom roles based on the requirement. You can create a custom authorize attribute per role or make the authorize attribute take in a list of strings (authorized roles) as parameters.